# Search inside all files of a Directory and then move using PHP

Tags: php, move, readdir

I have some issues, I need to search an specific text inside all the files of a directory, if the text appears inside one or more TXT I need to copy the file to two folders, and then delete the original one.

This is the code that I have so far (I know it's nothing)

```
<?php
$dir = 'C:\Users\ramosala\Desktop\New folder (2)';
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = scandir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            $Word="serie      = SMO";   
            if ($Word){
                echo "La factura pertenece a Coppel";
                $encuentra=TRUE;
                copy('C:\Users\ramosala\Desktop\New folder(2)',     'C:\Users\ramosala\Documents\Prueba Coppel\'');
                copy('C:\Users\ramosala\Desktop\New folder(2)', 'C:\Users\ramosala\Documents\Prueba Coppel 2\'');
                unlink('C:\Users\ramosala\Desktop\New folder(2)');
            }
            if($encuentra!=TRUE){
                echo 'No Pertenece a Coppel';

            }           
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: The problem with your question is A) Someone would have to write all this code for you, and B) We have no idea of your structure - application, framework, are you using a handful of scripts? So someone could write you an amazing PHP OOP Class to do this, and you might not have any idea how to use it, or be able to implement it. With something of this size, you need to make a start yourself, and when you get stuck ask a specific question about your code.

Comment: It'll probably be easiest to write this in bash with calls to `grep`, `cp` and `mv` or `rm`.  Alternatively, if you need more powerful string processing, perl is the way to go (IMO).  Try writing it and then post what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full prototype:

```
$sDirectory     = 'file-fun';
$sNewDirectory  = 'file-fun2';
$sNewDirectory2 = 'file-fun3';
if( !is_dir( $sNewDirectory ) )
{
    mkdir( $sNewDirectory, 0777, TRUE );
}
if( !is_dir( $sNewDirectory2 ) )
{
    mkdir( $sNewDirectory2, 0777, TRUE );
}
$sFilter = '12';
if( is_dir( $sDirectory ) ) 
{
    $rDir = opendir( $sDirectory );
    while( ( $sFile = readdir( $rDir ) ) !== FALSE ) 
    {
        if( ( $sFile == '.' ) || ( $sFile === '..' ) )
        {
            continue;
        }
        $sFilePath = $sDirectory . '/' . $sFile;
        $sContents = file_get_contents( $sFilePath );
        if( strpos( $sContents, $sFilter ) !== FALSE )
        {
            $sNewFileName  = $sNewDirectory . '/' . $sFile;
            $sNewFileName2 = $sNewDirectory2 . '/' . $sFile;
            if( !copy( $sFilePath, $sNewFileName ) || !copy( $sFilePath, $sNewFileName2 ) )
            {
                echo 'Could not move: ' . $sFile;
            }
            else
            {
                unlink( $sFilePath );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is really what I wanted to do, now Im just going to figure how add the line of thext that moves the file depending it's content.

Comment: I just have one question left, Is it possible to move the files to another computer in the local network?

Comment: Check out ftp_get and curl. Another option is to look at exec but I would be very careful with that command.